# pass fpassthru contents to variable

Tags: php

here's a portion of my code (taken from google charts example here http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/post_requests.html) that will display an image chart:

```
 $context = stream_context_create(
array('http' => array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'content' => http_build_query($chart))));
fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));
```

The problem is instead of displaying the image directly, I'd like to pass the contents of fpassthru (which essentially is the image) to a variable.. perhaps something like

```
$image = fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));
```

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$image = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

or [`stream_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) (but don't forget to [close](http://php.net/fclose) the file):

```
$f = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
$image = stream_get_contents($f);
fclose($f);
```