# How to assign SplFileObject::fpassthru output to variable

Tags: php, csv, splfileobject

I'm currently writing some data to an `SplFileObject` like this:

```
$fileObj = new SplFileObject('php://text/plain,', "w+");

foreach($data as $row) {

    $fileObj->fputcsv($row);
}
```

Now, I want to dump the whole output (string) to a variable.

I know that `SplFileObject::fgets` gets the output line by line (which requires a loop) but I want to get it in one go, ideally something like this:

```
$fileObj->rewind();
$output = $fileObj->fpassthru();
```

However, this does not work as it simply prints to standard output.

There's a solution for what I'm trying to achieve using `stream_get_contents()`:

[pass fpassthru contents to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771831/pass-fpassthru-contents-to-variable)

However, that method requires you to have direct access to the file handle.

`SplFileObject` hides the file handle in a private property and therefore not accessible.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Simple output buffering …?

Comment: @CBroe Good idea. Was hoping there might be an inbuilt function. But that might be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing, do a rewind() then you can read everything. The example is for understanding:

```
$fileObj = new SplFileObject('php://memory', "w+");
    
$row = [1,2,'test'];  //Test Data
    
$fileObj->fputcsv($row);
$fileObj->rewind();
    
//now Read
$rowCopy = $fileObj->fgetcsv();
    
var_dump($row == $rowCopy);//bool(true)

$fileObj->rewind();
$strLine = $fileObj->fgets();  //read as string
$expected = "1,2,test\n";

var_dump($strLine === $expected);  //bool(true)

//several lines
$fileObj->rewind();
$fileObj->fputcsv(['test2',3,4]);
$fileObj->fputcsv(['test3',5,6]);

$fileObj->rewind();
for($content = ""; $row = $fileObj->fgets(); $content .= $row);

var_dump($content === "test2,3,4\ntest3,5,6\n");  //bool(true)
```

If you absolutely have to fetch your content with only one command then you can do this too

```
// :
$length = $fileObj->ftell(); 
$fileObj->rewind();
$content = $fileObj->fread($length);
```

getSize() doesn't work here.

Comment: If you add a couple more rows to $fileObj you'll notice that fgets will only return a single line at a time. I want to get the whole lot

Comment: You can read in all lines with fgets() via a simple loop. I've added the example.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware about looping and calling `fgets()` but I wanted to avoid it

Comment: I added another variant.

Comment: Perfect. Works for me!

Comment: Could you please move your second answer to the top as that is the one I was after.

Comment: I remember poking around with `fread` but I think I used `getSize` instead, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an inbuilt function I've decided to do php output buffering as @CBroe had suggested.

```
...

$fileObj->rewind();

ob_start();

$fileObj->fpassthru();

$buffer = ob_get_clean();
```

See @jsplit's answer for a better method using `SplFileObject`s inbuilt functions